# What is “basho” in Kitaro Nishida’s philosophy?

Tags: reference-request, eastern-philosophy

Of course, I could just read his 100-page essay *The Logic of Place and the Religious Worldview,* but since it is regarded as extremely cryptic, I wanted to read some introductory texts (like by David A. Dilworth) to avoid serious misunderstandings – only to find out that those are quite cryptic themselves.

So what is “basho” (Japanese for “place” or “topos”) in Kitaro Nishida’s philosophy? Can we translate it into terms from Western philosophy? Or is there an accessible introduction to the concept of “basho”?

Comment: Nishida’s logic of basho (place) is his central *nondual* epistemic logic from the POV of a certain (outside) place without objective/subjective dichotomy, and in his most important essay of his later writings *The Logic of Place and the Religious Worldview*, he conjoined and applied his logic to some famous scriptural passages of Buddhism sutras such as Diamond Sutra, Prajnaparamita Sutra, Eightfold Negation of Madhyamika, etc. In short, logic of basho is like Kant's *transcendental* space and time...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is better not to worry exactly what 'Absolute Nothingness' is and look at what you are

> “Action-intuition” (koiteki chokkan) is Nishida's technical term for
> designating individual subjectivity in relation to Absolute
> Nothingness.

I would characterise Basho as the site - worldly action - of **spontaneous expression of *Buddha nature***

> a Zen adept can always be relied upon to manifest compassion, this
> once again being a spontaneous movement of the spirit

Every action does this to a greater or lesser extent

> Cognitive activities such as thinking or judging, willing, and
> intellectual intuition are all derivative forms of pure experience but
> still manifest it insofar as they are in action —when thinking,
> willing, etc. are going on.

And that extent depends on whether we see it for what it is

> Nishida calls each such circle a place or topos **[basho]**
> *to be and to be seen as what they are*. The final topos places
> self-awareness in the world of action and expression which
> contextualizes it, and ultimately in absolute nothingness., each alloowing things

Most fruitfully as belonging to the basho of "absolute nothingness"

---

I read Nidhisa ages ago now, but from memory it's only really the 'nothingness' which stumped me. **TL;DR** I'd say it's the how of insightful creativity.

Comment: I may have taken a few liberties with the quotes, but it's from memory kinda